# qtvars_Win32_Debug.props. What is and how to stop auto generate

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

Me trying to do a ' out of source build ',using vs2017 qt5.13 win10.

The project is written in c++,qt.

I can put compiler/linker generated  files (such as obj lib exe)out of source directory except this file:

'debug\qmake\qtvars_Win32_Debug.props'.

It  is generated automatically in the source directory every time I build the project.

How can I get rid of this file?

Comment: ken do you have an email or discord in which I could contact you?